# How can I sum numbers extracted by Select-String?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Supposing I have a file `numbers.txt`:

```
My number 1
...
My number 2
...
My number 3
...
```

I am trying to calculate sum of the numbers above. I extracted a number from each line like this:

```
PS > $numbers = gc .\numbers.txt | sls -Pattern "number\ (\d+)" |
>> select {$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value}
>>
PS > $numbers

$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value
-----------------------------
1
2
3
```

Looks like exactly what I want to sum. Next I am trying to apply the Measure-Object:

```
$numbers | measure -sum
```

```
measure : Input object "" is not numeric.
At line:1 char:12
+ $numbers | measure -sum
+            ~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidType: (:PSCustomObject) [Measure-Object], 
PSInvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : 
NonNumericInputObject,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MeasureObjectCommand
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array doesn't consist of numbers, but objects with a very long property-name (your scriptblock-value) which contains a string-value.

Replace [`Select-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Select-Object) with [`Foreach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object) to get the value, cast it to `int` and calculate. Ex:

```
$numbers = gc .\numbers.txt | sls -Pattern "number\ (\d+)" | Foreach-Object {$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value -as [int] }
($numbers | measure -sum).Sum
```

Comment: I can cast it to int even with Select-Object but I wonder is the length of property-name an obstacle for Measure-Object?

Comment: The casting-part was not the issue with `Select-Object`. The issue was that `Select-Object` used the expression (scriptblock) creates a property with the same name. We could give the column another name (@{n="ColumnName";e={$_.matches[0].etc}}`), but since you only want the number then it's much easier and cleaner to skip `Select-Object` in the first place and use `Foreach-Object`.

Comment: I see... It is not easier but useful for understanding. So when I tried to use `measure -sum "$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value"` it basically did not understand that name, right? Then what is the sense to have names we cannot access?

Comment: Cmdlets don't like the name because it contains many special characters since it's an expression. Why it won't work with single quotes when `$obj.'{$_.this.works}'`, I can't say. When using calculated columns, you are supposed to set a name like my example above. And with this limitation + the fact that you only store the number, I would say that foreach is still better than `.. | select @{n="Number";e={$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value -as [int]}}; ($numbers | Measure-Object -Property Number -Sum).Sum` (there are other ways to do it, but creating an object with one prop is still waste of time).

Comment: I am agree your way is better, just wanted to clarify things for myself.

Answer (score 1):

> Looks like exactly what I want to sum

No it doesn't, the output has a header row. If it was a simple array of integers then it would not, it would show as simply:

```
1
2
3
```

What you have created is an array of PowerShell objects, each with a property called `'$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value'`. You need something like:

```
$numbers = gc .\numbers.txt | sls -Pattern "number\ (\d+)" | ForEach {$_.matches[0].groups[1].Value}
```

instead.

Answer (score 1):

other method:

```
$template=@"
My number {number*:1}
My number {number*:2}
"@


#verbose version
(Get-Content C:\temp\number.txt | 
    ConvertFrom-String -TemplateContent $template | 
        measure -Sum number).Sum

#short version
(gc C:\temp\number.txt | cfs -TemplateContent $template | Measure -Sum number).Sum
```

Comment: Nice, but it will work only if strings are of fixed format where only number can change, right? In real life I have log line like this: `{date} [{thread}] Got N messages {guid}`.

Comment: It work if string are number (1, 2, 123, 123.456). Give a complet example of your content file

Comment: `23:52:49 [10] Got 2 messages \ 23:52:50 [12] Some irrelevant stuff \ 23:52:51 [42] Got 5 messages \ ...`